# Scope variable are not available in the template

Tags: angularjs, scope

I started a project with angular-seed. I mixed it with another project in which has jQuery. I can't reach the scope variables in my template.

**JS:**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.showView = true;
    $scope.proBlock = false;
    $scope.modelBlock = false;

    $.when(dbReadyDeferred).then(function() {
        $scope.proBlock = true;
        console.log('dbReadyDeferred.state()',dbReadyDeferred.state());
    });
...
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-show="showView">
    {{proBlock}}
</div>
```

In the browser, it shows: `false`. Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: directly it show's false or div itself  not showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your function `$.when(dbReadyDeferred).then(function() {})` is being called then change your controller code like this:

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.showView = true;
    $scope.proBlock = false;
    $scope.modelBlock = false;

    $.when(dbReadyDeferred).then(function() {
        $timeout(function() {
             $scope.proBlock = true;
             console.log('dbReadyDeferred.state()',dbReadyDeferred.state());
        });
    });
}]);
```

Since, you are changing the `$scope.proBlock` value using jQuery so the Angular is unaware of this change and we need to explicitly tell Angular to run the digest cycle.

We can use `$scope.$apply()` as well but wrapping the call into `$timeout` function is a cleaner approach.

Read more: [AngularJS with Ajax Form submission needing to click twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810690/angularjs-with-ajax-form-submission-needing-to-click-twice/33810890#33810890)

**Update:**

You can modify your resolve variable like this:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
    controller: 'View1Ctrl'.
    resolve: {
         dbState: ['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q) {
               var promise = $q.when(dbReadyDeferred)

               promise.then(function() {
                   $rootScope.$broadcast("dbStateReady");
               });
               return promise;
         }]
    }
  });
}])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.showView = true;
    $scope.proBlock = false;
    $scope.modelBlock = false;

    var deregisterFunction = $scope.$on("dbStateReady", function() {
        $scope.proBlock = true;
        console.log('dbReadyDeferred.state()',dbReadyDeferred.state());
        deregisterFunction();   // Remove this watch for $on listener
    });
});
```

Basically, we moved the `$q.when` (like @shushanthp mentioned) to the `resolve` and using `$broadcast` to know about when the db state is ready using `$on`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. Is there a way to make this cleaner and pass the deferred variable to the `resolve` property of $routeProvider ? I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943845/routeprovider-resolve-with-deferred-variable

Comment: Thanks. But I don't see the point to monitor the broadcasted event "dbStateReady", because the controller's code is only gonna be executed **once** `dbReadyDeferred` is resolved, is it right ? So `dbStateReady` will have necessarily fired one the controller's code starts to execute, won't it ?

Comment: You are absolutely right. You should be keeping an eye on improving performance of your code. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

As your using `$.when`, which is out of Angular world, you have to explicitly use `$timeout` or `$scope.$digest`.

You can use Angular's promise library which is `$q.when` method, as AngularJS will attach the watch to it and changes accordingly.

```
 $q.when(dbReadyDeferred).then(function() {
      $scope.proBlock = true;
      console.log('dbReadyDeferred.state()',dbReadyDeferred.state());
 });
```

If you want to use `jQuery.when` method, then used `$timeout` as below:

```
$.when(dbReadyDeferred).then(function() {
     $timeout(function() {
         $scope.proBlock = true;
        console.log('dbReadyDeferred.state()',dbReadyDeferred.state());
       },0,false) // false it doesnt invoke digest again which helps in performance

    });
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot, `$q.when` works well. Do you how to pass this to the `resolve` of the route provider?